# Unhandled Rejection (Error): Invalid hook call React Stripe Fpx

Tags: reactjs, stripe-payments

I have issue when submit my FpxBank Element on ReactJS.

this error show when i submit paymentFpx
[image: Submit Error]

this is my FpxBank Element Component

Fpx.Js

```js
import React, {useEffect} from 'react';
import {withRouter, useLocation} from 'react-router-dom';
import {FpxBankElement, Elements, useStripe, useElements} from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';
import {loadStripe} from '@stripe/stripe-js';



const stripePromise = loadStripe("pk_test_rgWMA3zxjAtwaB6iV8b5W40x");

const FpxForm = () => {
  return (
    <Elements stripe={stripePromise}>
        <FpxBankElement options={{accountHolderType: 'individual'}} />
    </Elements>
  );
};


export default FpxForm;
```

this is my cart page:

```js
        else if(this.props.productInput.payment_method == 'fpx'){
            const stripe = useStripe();
            const elements = useElements();
            const result = await stripe.confirmFpxPayment('pk_test_rgWMA3zxjAtwaB6iV8sb5W40x', {
                payment_method: {
                  fpx: elements.getElement(FpxBankElement)  ,
                },
                // Return URL where the customer should be redirected after the authorization
                return_url: `${window.location.href}`,
              });
            
              if (result.error) {
                // Inform the customer that there was an error.
                const errorElement = document.getElementById('error-message');
                errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
              }
        }
```

any solution or help?

Comment: Is your cart page class component or functional component?

Comment: cart page using class component

Comment: You can't use hooks inside class components. You are calling useStripe() hook in your cart page. To make this work you must refactor your cart page to be functional component

Comment: Any solution instead change my cart page to functional component? because my team code is work for this component, only issue for this part

Comment: useStripe() is a hook that allows a functional component to access the Stripe object, therefore it can only be used in functional components. If you want to keep using it, you must refactor your code. Check out this https://linguinecode.com/post/integrate-stripe-payment-form-with-react

Comment: i success create child bankComponent, i want to call child functional component method from parent class component. any clue?